# Ambiguous Column Name in Select Statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

This query is returning the error "ambiguous column name courses.scheduleNumber". I searched for a solution to the problem, however, a commonly suggested fix was to qualify all of the column names with the table name, which I have already done.

```
SELECT
  courses.scheduleNumber,
  courses.subject,
  courses.courseNumber,
  courses.sectionNumber,
  courses.credits,
  courses.title,
  courses.room,
  courses.days,
  rooms.building,
  rooms.room,
  courses.startTime,
  courses.endTime,
  courses.instructor
FROM courses
LEFT JOIN courseRooms 
  ON courses.scheduleNumber=courseRooms.scheduleNumber
LEFT JOIN courses 
  ON courseRooms.building=rooms.building AND courseRooms.room=rooms.room;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you mean for that final `LEFT JOIN courses` to be a `LEFT JOIN rooms` ?

Answer (score 0):

Two "courses" in your from clause. Replace the "courses" in final left join with "rooms". It should work then.

Answer (score -1):

You have `courses` twice in your `from` clause.